# What can I call the English-speaking section of the Internet?

Tags: word-request

Is there such a term for this?

E.g. in Russia we call Russian-speaking section "runet". "Runet" is a useful term. You can search in runet, analyze runet, compare runet with "english-speaking section of the Internet".

As an example, I've searched for a term in runet and found nothing. That's why I'm trying to ask in "English-speaking section of the Internet". (Too long, isn't it?)

EngNet is "engeneering network" as far as I can see.

---

Well, I've got the idea. These terms are useful only if are using more than one language. Btw, I've found some interesting stats about net: 1 English 52.3% 2 Russian 6.4% 3 Japanese 5.7% 4 German 5.4% 5 Spanish 5.0% (src: en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Languages_used_on_the_Internet)

Comment: What about *"English forum"*, but what's wrong with *"English-speaking zone or site"*?

Comment: I don't think a name is necessary to identify if the site is Anglophone (English speaking) or not, it's kind of obvious when you Google in English what zone you're entering in. Could you explain in your question, a bit more about the usage of "runet", it sounds interesting.

Comment: Why not "engnet" copied off of "runet"?

Comment: I think you could appropriate "EngNet" for your own use. But you have to realize, I think the term "runet" only came into existence because it had been a minority, whereas, according to Mozilla, [English-language websites are the majority](https://internethealthreport.org/v01/stories/when-the-internet-doesnt-speak-your-language/). I'm not saying anything about the political ramifications of this, I'm just saying that the majority of people would expect a website to be in English, but not always expect it to be in Russian. (Cont'd.)

Comment: (Cont'd.) And so it's not that there is an "English-speaking zone of the Internet," but it's more that there's a "Russian-speaking zone of the Internet which is already in English." Again, I'm not making any comments about the political implications, simply stating the facts based on third-party statistics.

Comment: English speakers refer to it as "the internet".  :)

Comment: As other people have said, I don't think there's a specific term for "English-language websites", because it's kind of the standard, expected thing, the [unmarked case](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Markedness), kind of like how there is no single, simple, common term for "cat that *does* have a tail".  If you have to specify, something like "English-language websites" is probably how you would have to do it.

Comment: Also, the word **zone** is inapt.

Comment: "English-speaking section of the Internet" is what I'd expect to read.

Answer (score 1):

How about just

> English *(language)* sites.

Use "***language***" To differentiate from the geographic portion of the UK, but those will also be in English. :)

Since if I gave you a link, I might say

> Here's the link to what you want, but it's in German.

My guess is **runet** is a portmanteau coined by English speakers.

Answer (score 1):

This isn't restricted to the Internet, but you might consider using 'Anglosphere'.

[Anglosphere](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/Anglosphere) (MW)

> the countries of the world in which the English language and cultural values predominate